# How to shut down the system

Tags: shutdown

How do I turn Ubuntu off?

I can't find a button called shut down or turn off.

Answer (score 1):

Run the below commands on terminal to poweroff,

```
sudo shutdown -P now
```

OR

```
sudo poweroff
```

OR

Click on the gear icon in the top-right corner  and  select Shutdown option from the list.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the default Ubuntu installation (with "Unity"), there should be a gear-like icon in the extreme top-right of your screen... Click this, followed by "Shut down...", then just follow the bouncing ball.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this command "shutdown now".